# How to call a client side function with signalr even it is written in other client side hub

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I make request to server with  **invoice_hub**. After full execution of this method i want to invoke a client side method written in **item_hub**

thanks...

Comment: Unclear question. Please explain more. What did you tried? Which code do you have?.....

Comment: $.connection.hub.saveinvoice.save=function(){      }//making  request to save invoice <br/> on saving the invoice i want to show a success message  <br/> And the method for showing the msg is in $.connection.hub.servermsg.show <br/> Now i want to call this client side method from saleinvoice server HUB

Comment: Need more explanation ask me but please help me to solve this

Comment: Please modify your question. Not add the code as comment